# How to change the clock output speed with a divider?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to set up a clock and a divider to output a 2 hz clock signal for another section of my code. I have two modules, one for the clock, and one for the divider, and I have it set up so that the output of the clock is the input to the divider, but when I take the output of the divider, it is the same speed as just having the clock. Is there something I am missing?

Here is the code for the clock module:

```
module clock(clk);

output reg clk; 
 
 always 
     #5 
      clk = ~clk;
 initial 
     clk = 0;
      
endmodule
```

Here is the code for the divider module:

```
module clock_div(clk_in, reset, clk_out);
    input clk_in;
    input reset;
    output reg clk_out;

    parameter divider = 50000000;
    parameter n = 24;
    reg [n-1:0] count;
    
    initial begin
        clk_out <= 1'b0;
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk_in or posedge reset) begin
        if(reset) begin
            count <= 0;
            clk_out <= 1'b0;
        end
        else begin
            if(count == divider) begin
                count <= 0;
                clk_out <= ~clk_out;
            end
            else begin
                count <= count + 1'b1;
            end
        end
    end
    
endmodule
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need to instantiate clock_div inside clock module. Connect clk output of clock module to clk_in input of clk_div instance. Create a wire clk_out in the clock module and dump its transitions in a waveform.

Answer (score 0):

Your code represents just parts of the environment and cannot work by itself. So, is impossible to understand how you simulated it and monitored the clocks.

You need to connect those parts together, so that your clock is fed into the divider module and the output is monitored. So, here is an example of a test bench module which does it. You can create your own based on this example.

```
module top;
  wire clk, div_clk;
  reg reset;
  
  // instantiate your module, this part is required for simulation or fpga
  // this instantiates the clock module and generated base clock
  clock clock(.clk(clk));
  // this instantiates the divider module, feeding in the clock from the previous module
  clock_div clock_div(.clk_in(clk), .reset(reset), .clk_out(div_clk)); 
  
  // here is an example of a test bench code for simulation only
  initial begin
    // just prints out values of both clocks; you can generate waveforms instead.
    $monitor(clk, div_clk);
    
    // handle initial reset
    reset = 1;
    #10 reset = 0;

    // let it simulate for a certain amount of time and finish
    #2_0000_0000 $finish; 
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The modules are actually connected using a schematic file. I did this because this clock and divider is a part of a larger project that has other components that were done in schematic files. Is doing that what is messing me up?

Comment: you did not show how you connected the instances. What are 'schematic files'?